# Anime movie about futuristic racing

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I remember that I watched an anime movie about futuristic racing with spaceships, like the ones in *Star Wars: The Phantom Menace* or like *Oban*. The main character was a little boy with a green helmet and goggles.

Does anybody know it?

Comment: Consider having a look at ["How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/40711) for a checklist that could help you remember further details to narrow down the search.

Answer (score 8):

I think it may be *Redline*. Although there is no boy with a green helmet and goggles, one of the main characters is a girl with green hair and goggles (as you can see in the poster below).

[image: Redline poster of girl with green hair]

You can see the trailer below.